# Should I tell new employer I omitted a job on CV?

Tags: resume, job-search, background-check

I'm a student and I have occupied a position shortly (work less than 7 days in total over 4 months) in a franchise during my studies a few years ago, but didn't make through the probation period, which I felt was due to the lack of trainings and my lack of motivation (I didn't received any training there and was too busy with my studies to bother telling the supervisor). Since then, I had a few more short-term summer job experiences elsewhere, but with better references and experiences. I also had similar short term experiences (a few days of work over a period of a month), but decided to keep it on my CV since I made a good impression, but the reason for my termination was out of my control (they were overstaffed)

I've got a new offer for a much higher up but related position recently in the same franchise, but I omit to put my first job on the CV since I am now much more capable than before and having it on my CV would make me seem like I am unable to hold a job.

They have already contacted my references and gave me all the paperworks. I'm concerned however that my omission might show up in their third party background check once I have submitted said paperworks. They have not asked me for an employment history, but they did asked me to sign a background check form which says that any omission on my CV might be a reason for termination.

Should I tell my employer prior to the background check in good faith? If yes, how should I approach the situation? If no, what are the likelihood that they will find out and how will it reflect on me as a employee?

thank you very much in advance

Comment: It's up to you what you put on your CV - you are not obligated to include everything (omitting things is perfectly normal, otherwise they would be too long) - they may ask for your entire employment history over the last X years, and there I would include it, as they will often ask you to sign/certify that it is correct there. It would end up being a non-issue at that point though, and while you should be prepared to explain it, let them bring it up if it is a concern - don't turn any issues into a red flag unless the employer also sees it as a potential red flag.

Comment: Thank you very for your reply! They have not asked me for an employment history, but they did asked me to sign a background check form which says that any omission on my CV might be a reason for termination. By signing this form, will I be legally obliged to correct any job missing on my CV?

Comment: I find that as an odd thing to request, as a [CV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curriculum_vitae) is **your** format/style, not theirs, and intended to be an overview, not a comprehensive history - I would ask to clarify what they need included (ask for a full list of items) in the CV and add it if they mention it. Could I also ask what country you are in? perhaps a CV there is different from what I imagine when I hear of a CV (I am familiar with U.S. systems)

Comment: I'll ask them to clarify before handing over the forms. I am from Canada.

Comment: totally agree with user2813274.  Perhaps by 'omission' they mean 'false claims and outright lies'?  Because when you turn in a CV there is no agreement by either party that it will include every single thing you've ever done, that's patently ridiculous.  Your reasons for leaving that experience off are perfectly reasonable - you are no longer the same person and it's not relevant to the future.  And working less than 7 days in total over 4 months probably didn't amount to enough for you to consider it work experience.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input Joe!

I guess I am only worried because my newest job is in the same franchise as my first job, and thus most likely to show up as an omission in a background check. Also, I work in a domain with a lot of emphasis on ethics and honesty (I handle sensitive information), and I don't want to give out the wrong impression that I am a liar by omission even though my first job experience has become a lot less relevant now

Comment: Hi Zcode2, welcome to The Workplace! As a reminder to everyone, please avoid using comments for extended discussion. Instead, please use [chat]. On Workplace SE, comments are intended to help improve a post. Please see [What "comments" are not...](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/72/what-comments-are-not) for more details.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Would you include short work experience in your CV?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/973/would-you-include-short-work-experience-in-your-cv)

Answer (score 3):

**No you don't need to tell them every job which you have done.**

You mentioned that you signed a form which said

> any omission on my CV might be a reason for termination

I think what was intended by this is if you [lied on your resume](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/21359), they don't have to hire you.

For example, say that on my resume I stated that I worked for Google for a year as an engineer and this led me to being selected for a job at Twitter. If I had never actually worked for Google or maybe I lied that I was a programmers when I was actually a janitor, then they might be grounds for not hiring me (even after they had extended an offer).

I have actually had a similar experience, previously I got employed at a high-tech job for a grand total of 2 days (it was supposed to be many months) due to a series of events beyond my control. I never listed it on my resume because it was just too complicated to try and explain.

I think [this question's first answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/18469) says it pretty well. The second paragraph is not really applicable since you were only at this company a few days over a long period of time.

Comment: Thank you for your input, it's very reassuring and appreciated! Do you think the fact that my new position and old position were essentially in the same company (same franchise) would raise any red flag later on?

Comment: @Zcode2 Not unless you were fired (not let go - actually terminated). If you have proven to the company that you were a 'bad employee' then yes, *potential* red flags. Additionally corporations are big and internal communication is not always stellar. TLDR; you're probably ok.

Answer (score 1):

It is common practice to leave positions off of your resume.  People leave positions off for many reasons.  The position has no direct relevance to the job you are applying for.  For example, I was out of work for a while and took a job as a telemarketer to make some money.  I work in the IT field and there is no benefit for me to list a completely unrelated job position on my resume.  Another reason for leaving a position off of a resume is time.  It is perfectly acceptable to leave a position off of your job if it occurred a long time ago.  One example, for me, is that when I first left college I was a web developer.  That was 20 years ago.  Although I am in the IT field now, the skills and technologies I used back then are obsolete.  I would probably mention in the interview that I have had experience, but I leave it off my resume.  There are plenty of other valid reasons to leave something off your resume.  I worked at a company for 2 months and then the company was bought out and shutdown.  I used to list it on my resume.  But potential employers were unable to verify the company existed or contact my supervisor.  I realized that it was causing more harm than good to put it on my resume.  There a many other reasons to leave a position off you resume.

It is fairly standard for a company to say an omission is reasons for termination.  Statements like that are more to cover their butts.  If a company was to terminate a person, they want to be able to build up as much factual and pertinent information before terminating an employee in case that employee sues them.

PS

Adding after my answer.  If I listed every job I have ever had, my resume would be 10 pages long.  Thats not a good thing.

Comment: I see your reasoning; it is reassuring to know. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I would not mention any of the jobs on your CV or to employers.  They both sound like they were not good companies to work for, and the other, longer positions back that up.  Most college graduates have held at least one odd job that didn't work out, its normal, and nothing to be ashamed or afraid of.

If the company ask you about them, say something like

> Those positions were extremely short, and not at all relevant to my position now.

Answer (score 0):

"...they did asked me to sign a background check form which says that any omission on my CV might be a reason for termination."

The key word is "might" - it's not "will" as in "it will be a reason for termination" Since your work at the franchise was from a few years ago and it was super low level work, chances are pretty good that they might not even have on file your work experience any more, as per their data retention policies.

My resume is three pages. I delete stuff from it regularly to keep the length of my resume below my three-page limit. You might similarly want to keep your resume length below say your one-page limit, which means that over time, some of your stuff on your resume has to go. C'est la vie.

If they mention your work experience from a few years ago, don't make a big deal of it - It's a big deal for them if you choose to make a big deal of it. Point out that

1. you have to keep your resume at one page and shorter
2. That experience no longer reflects the person you are now, and it hasn't reflected the person you are for years.
3. You did not learn much from that experience back then, mainly because you were not ready to learn from that experience back then. You have changed in a big way since.
4. Exude cooperation. Tell them that if they have any question about your experience back then, you'll be glad to answer.
5. Exude confidence. Tell them that you are not afraid to disclose anything from back then that puts you in a bad light, because you haven't been the person you were back then for a long, long time. On the other hand, the fact that you are not afraid does not preclude you from being embarrassed as you remember :)
6. Exude interest for the position. Tell them one of the positive aspects of your previous experience back then is that you learned to really appreciate the franchise and the workers and the people you worked with, and that's why you are applying and why you are so intensely interested in the position offered.

In summary, you don't have to tell the franchise that you used to work for them but you have to be ready to give your best shot if they ever bring it up. If you don't make a big deal out of it, chances are pretty good they won't. If you can make an inspirational narrative out of it, they will be inspired.

Comment: I make sure to prepare myself should they bring it up; thank you very much for your thoughtful response!